# How do I encapsulate a collection into a "complex type" object with Ef Core (example included)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I would like to map, in Ef Core, a complex type (in other words a type not directly mapped to a table) that does hold a list of object that is directly mapped to a table.

*Consider following example* below, where you'll find that the Diary logic (of which I now only show *AddEntry*) is separated from the Request class, as it has no concern being there.

I have no issues using *.OwnsOne* in Ef Core when using simpler types where the data is stored in the same table (e.g.: here it would be in the Requests table); but I have no idea or clue how I would map in *OnConfiguring* this situation.

- **C# model:**

```
public class Request : DbEntity {
   public Diary { get; set; }
}

public class DiaryEntry : DbEntity {
   public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
   public Request Request { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }   
}

public class Diary {
   private readonly List<DiaryEntry> _entries = new List<DiaryEntry>();
   public Request Request { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<DiaryEntry> Entries => _entries;
   public Diary AddEntry(DiaryEntry diaryEntry) {
      if(diaryEntry != null)
         _entries.Add(diaryEntry);
      return this;
   }
}
```

- **SQL Structure**

  - Requests is a table that is mapped in EfCore to the Entity Request
  - DiaryEntries is a table that exists in EfCore and is indirectly mapped with a DbSet with Request as "HasOne" so that it has a relation.
  - The table 'Diary' does not exist, it is a 'complex type' that encapsulates logic, so I don't have to deal with it in the 'Request' type in C#

Comment: Since DiaryEntry references Request, why not add a collection navigation property to the Request class that would allow you to use EF Core fluent syntax to retrieve the list? E.g. `public ICollection<DiaryEntry> DiaryEntries { get; set; }`

Comment: That is exactly what I want to avoid as "Diary" will hold logic that is only useful for the collection of DiaryEntries, and not useful on the Request class. In other words I want to respect the SRP as much as I can and not clutter Request with logic that has no real meaning to the "request" itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe anything like this is supported in Entity Framework as complex types are designed to support organizing properties on one table into related classes without relational tables. In your case you would like to take relational tables and map an intermediate class to avoid having rules about managing the child collection in the parent class.

One option I can put forward to help address the separation of concerns you appear to want to have between your classes is to leverage extension methods for the collection-specific logic you want exposed for a Diary.

For example:

```
[Table("Requests")]
public class Request
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<DiaryEntry> Diary { get; protected set; } = new List<DiaryEntry>();
}

[Table("DiaryEntries")]
public class DiaryEntry
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DiaryEntryId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

Here we expose the Diary as `IEnumerable<DiaryEntry>` so consumers of the entity cannot modify the collection etc. From there the diary functionality can be managed by extensions:

```
public static class DiaryExtensions
{
    public static DiaryEntry AddEntry(this IEnumerable<DiaryEntry> diary, DiaryEntry newEntry)
    {
        ICollection<DiaryEntry> diaryList = (ICollection<DiaryEntry>)diary;
        if (newEntry != null)
            diaryList.Add(newEntry);

        return newEntry;
    }
}
```

Personally though I would have this logic in Request as the diary entries are associated to the request. To separate the diary specific logic I would utilize partial classes but maintain responsibility for the supported behaviour in the class that contains them.

Comment: I have actually gone with a similar route indeed now, as pragmatic as can be, and indeed leveraging the partial classes functionality we have in the language to make it at least "visually" seperate.

I however thought there might have been another solution in EF, but if not, then this is perfectly acceptable. Thanks for your response!